# How to make a 2 level factor as my outcome column

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation, cart

I am trying to do a 10 fold cross validation on a spam data set where the response column is in zeros and ones. The spam data set consists of 58 columns where the last column represents whether the entity is a spam or not. I have written the following code :

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)
set.seed(110)
spam <-read.table("/Data Analytics/spam.tsv", header = FALSE)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y =spam$V58, p =.70, list =FALSE)
training <-spam[inTrain,]
test <- spam[-inTrain,]
nrow(training)
train_control<- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
model<- train(V58~., data=training, trControl=train_control, 
method="rpart")
fit <- rpart(V58 ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V5 + V6 + V7, method ="class", data =training)
printcp(fit)
plotcp(fit)
```

I am getting a warning message as the following:

```
You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.
2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

Is there any way to fix this?
Also I want to create a classification tree with 100 terminal nodes based on the data provided, any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to warning message, convert dependent variable to factor, i.e. `spam$V58 = as.factor(spam$V58)`.

When it comes to 100 nodes, there is a `prune` function in `rpart` package which will allow you to cut the tree - you need to choose `cp` parameter so that you have desired number of nodes.

Comment: I added the `spam$V58 =as.factor(spam$V58)` before the train function line and it's still giving the same error. Have I missed something?

Comment: Add this line just after read.table, it refers to „spam” dataset

Comment: Great it worked!

Comment: Great, then please mark my answer as the answer to your question. Thanks.